# SpecFlow features in C# with german Umlaute

Tags: c#, specflow

I'm trying to get my features generated in C# right. But the SpecFlow generator doesn't seem to like german umlauts (like ä, ö or ü).
When I try to define a scenario or a step the Encoding breaks it somewhere.

Example 1:
`Scenario: Aufruf der Tabelle auf verschiedenen Endgeräten`
will be generated as
`[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.DescriptionAttribute("Aufruf der Tabelle auf verschiedenen Endger„ten")]`

Example 2:
`When I click the subheadline "ärztliche Behandlung"`
will be generated as
`testRunner.When("I click the subheadline \"„rztliche Behandlung\"", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "When ");`

I tried to save the feature file as UTF-8 without and with BOM but with no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the VS extension and is documented in issue https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1205

You can download the fixed version manually or wait until we upload it to the marketplace.
This will happen in the next days.

Comment: Days are now minutes. I uploaded the extensions 30min ago. It should be in the next hours available for you to update. If you have still problems, please open an issue here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues